# convert *.mpls (a Blu-ray audio) to tracked FLAC by chapters

Tags: ffmpeg, blu-ray

how to convert *.mpls (bluRai audio) to tracked FLAC with chapters?
as many single songs

```
ffmpeg -i "f:\BDMV\STREAM\00003.m2ts" -map 0:4 "E:\Downloads\Blu-ray Disc.flac"
```

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

```
PS E:\Downloads> ffprobe -i "f:\BDMV\STREAM\00003.m2ts"
ffprobe version 2022-03-28-git-5ee198f9aa-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.0 (Rev7, Built by MSYS2 project)
****
[mpegts @ 0000023c0e7f7d40] stream 0 : no PTS found at end of file, duration not set
Input #0, mpegts, from 'f:\BDMV\STREAM\00003.m2ts':
  Duration: 00:41:53.34, start: 600.000000, bitrate: 26741 kb/s
  Program 1
  Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn
  Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: truehd (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 7.1, s32 (24 bit)
  Stream #0:2[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 640 kb/s
  Stream #0:3[0x1101]: Audio: dts (DTS-HD MA) ([134][0][0][0] / 0x0086), 96000 Hz, 5.1(side), s32p (24 bit)
  Stream #0:4[0x1102]: Audio: dts (DTS-HD MA) ([134][0][0][0] / 0x0086), 192000 Hz, stereo, s32p (24 bit)
```